# display csv file on excel

Tags: android, excel, csv

The following code take all data from database and write it in SDCard as CSV format. my problem is when i open the file in Excel it write the data in this format

**Example**

254868,2356489,4587963,787954,7895487,452369,4546545

but i want the result to be like this:

```
254868
2356489
4587963
7879544
7895487
4523697
4546545
```

**Here is the code**

```
if (root.canWrite()){  
                        File fileDir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath()+"/fun/");  
                        fileDir.mkdirs();  


                        File file= new File(fileDir, "itisfun.csv");  
                        FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(file);  
                        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);  
                        out.write( dbUser.getMeterNUmber2(dd,sp).toString()+"\n" ); 
                        //out.write( "\"" );


                        out.close();  
                    }  
                } catch (IOException e) {  
                    Log.e("ERROR:---", "Could not write file to SDCard" +  e.getMessage());  
                }
```

Comment: I don't see any formatting code, that would enter newline `\n` after each number. From what i see, You present the code to dump a variable to file. Is there some other place in your code you can add `\n` after every number?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
String[] div = dbUser.getMeterNUmber2(dd,sp).toString().split(',');
for (int i =0; i<div.length;i++)
out.write( div[i] +"\n" );
```

I assume

```
dbUser.getMeterNUmber2(dd,sp).toString()
```

returns

```
254868,2356489,4587963,787954,7895487,452369,4546545
```

Comment: Thanx it works fine. can you help me with it so that it can display those numbers and next to them display the next column from database which have names?

Comment: so there you need to change the DB query, to some thing that return. number,name\n

Comment: the other unfavored way to do this will be by appending <,name> to end of each row in your csv.

Comment: other possible way is using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYmbolic_LinK_%28SYLK%29 formate

Answer (score 0):

Check in the getMeterNUmber2 function whether it writes comma or newline after each record. If you use comma then excel is correct to put them all on one line, in columns. If you use newline then one should be in each row like you want.